# I want to get all json files from reslource/json path and do versioning it, but I dont know which function I have to use

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I want to take all json files from path resources/json/ and do versioning so that when json files changed user can reload it, but I dont know which function I have to use

I changeed webpack.mix.js:

```
mix
    .setPublicPath('public/build')
    .setResourceRoot('build')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'css')
    //.json('resources/assets/json/*', 'json')
    .version();
```

but I dont know how to copy from dir into another dir and in write mix-manifest file write all json files with hash

Comment: output of the error is mix.setPublicPath(...).setResourceRoot(...).js(...).sass(...).json is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix
    .setPublicPath('public/build')
    .setResourceRoot('build')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'css')
    .copyDirectory('resources/assets/json', 'public/build/json')
    .version(['public/build/json']);
```

and two times `npm run dev`, because mix is not waiting for copying files, `.then()` not helped, so two times `npm run dev`.